# why convertotimezone() function is not available in AZURE DATA FACTORY for my company login?

Tags: azure, oracle11g, timestamp-with-timezone

I am not seeing converttotimezone() function is not available in azure data factory expression builder, I am trying to save one date column from csv file to oracle column TIMSTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE

Tried many things from microsoft url's

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones?view=windows-11#time-zones

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toTimestamp()` function in ADF. Because, there is no function called `converttotimezone()` in azure data factory expression builder.

**Syntax:**

`toTimestamp(_<string>_  : any, [_<timestamp format>_  : string], [_<time zone>_  : string]) => timestamp`

Example to use the  `toTimestamp`  function in Azure Data Factory to convert a string value to a timestamp value in the  `PST`  timezone:

```
toTimestamp(date_col, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'PST')
```

[image]

This will convert the `date_col` to a timestamp value in the  `PST`  timezone. You can use this function for your timezone.